# Assignment of variables in Python - Strange behavior

Tags: python, variables, variable-assignment

I'm currently doing some stuffs with Python and I get some strange behavior when assigning variables. For example, I set "a" to 0.1 in the ipython console :

```
In [1]: a = 0.1
```

Then I print a :

```
In [2]: a
Out[2]: 0.10000000000000001

In [3]: a == 0.1
Out[3]: True

In [4]: a == 0.10000000000000001
Out[4]: True
```

Okay, maybe it's because of the finite representation of numbers (the last 1 is at the 16th place). But then :

```
In [17]: 1 == 0.10000000000000001
Out[17]: False
```

Do I have to be scared by this ? Because I am ! ;-)

Comment: *"maybe it's because of the finite representation of numbers"* Yes! In which universe should `1 == 0.10000000000000001` (and therefore `1 == 0.1`) be true?

Comment: See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10481156/double-or-float-datatype-doesnt-addup-properly-in-a-loop) question.

Comment: @NiklasB.: "Do I have to be scared by this?"

Comment: @Chris: I saw that :) The point is, what is "this" referring to? `1 != 0.1`? I would rather be scared if this were *not* the case.

Comment: Okay, thanks for these answers. How can I close the topic ? (Feel too stupid by writing `1==0.100...` -_- )

Comment: @NiklasB.: now if only it had been formatted as "Do I have to be scared by `this`?"...

Comment: @Chris: The answer to that would be straightforward: "Yes, now go use a better programming language" :)

Comment: @NiklasB. Ok I'll mark a good answer. Why Python is not the best programming language ? ;o)

Comment: @Bagheera: Python is a good choice, it doesn't have `this` :P No seriously, that was just a bad joke, Java and C++ are fine languages as well. Have fun coding!

Comment: This stuff is documented in the manual of _every_ language that uses floating point numbers. Does anyone read for themselves anymore?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check the [Floating Point Arithmetic: Issues and Limitations](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/floatingpoint.html) part of the Python tutorials - what you describe is inherent weirdness with the float data type (nothing Python specific)

Also, be aware that `repr()` (string representation) shows the float with pretty-looking rounding - your first `a` example isn't exactly `0.1`, which can be seen if you print it with more precision:

```
>>> a
0.1
>>> print "%.50f" % a
0.10000000000000000555111512312578270211815834045410
```

Answer (score 1):

No, you don't have to be scared. It's strictly non-mandatory and I'd consider it a waste of energy, really.

Just understand the phenomenon (you've already recognised it) and use `Decimal` when necessary.

Comment: Awww... if only I'd been Jon Skeet I would have been up to twenty votes by now.

Comment: you have to answer the same question for C# to get the 20 votes

Comment: So is *that* the reason why people still use C#? Because of the votes possible, and perhaps the thrill of competition with Jon Skeet? Ah hah! Item number one in the Plan for Python World Domination: eliminate Jon Skeet!